# How to minimal setup antehanler into chain-minimal (sdk 0.50.x, go 1.21)

Tags: cosmos-sdk

I'm building a module that manage minimum gas price for my chain and I can set minimum gas price using tx instead of setting it in config file. I'm a bit confused implementing my ante handler into my chain-minimal or cosmos-sdk. Is there any tutorial for this? Please give me some guides. Thanks